# IEnumerable<T> to Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Having `IEnumerable<Order> orders`, how to get a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Order>>` using Linq, where the key is `Order.CustomerName` mapped to a `IEnumerable` of customer's orders.

`orders.ToDictionary(order => order.CustomerName)` is not going to work right away, since there could be multiple orders that could have the same CustomerName.

**Solution:** `orders.ToLookup(order => order.CustomerName);`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [ILookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) interface is designed for this purpose, and represents a dictionary-like structure that contains many values per key. It has similar performance characteristics to those of a dictionary (i.e. it's a hashtable type structure)

You can create an [ILookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) using the [.ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073.aspx) extension method as follows:

```
ILookup<string, Order> ordersLookup = orders.ToLookup(o => o.CustomerName)
```

then:

```
IEnumerable<Order> someCustomersOrders = ordersLookup[someCustomerName];
```

Comment: +1 That's an awesome interface. Never heard of it before today.

Comment: Most people don't know about Lookups, but this is a great example of its use.  This is preferable to a Dictionary with an enumerable as the value.

Comment: @SimpleCoder it's used all over the place internally in Linq2Objects

Comment: @spender: I'll have to check that out. Right now I'm working on a project that might benefit from ILookup, so I'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 13):

Just an alternative to @spender's answer, if you *really* want a type `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Order>>`, you could use:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<Order>> dictionary = orders
        .GroupBy(order => order.CustomerName)
        .ToDictionary(groupedOrders => groupedOrders.Key, 
                          groupedOrders => (IEnumerable<Order>)groupedOrders);
```

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but that'll do it too.

Comment: Why? If you can do LINQ you can do ILookup, why re-invent a class that already exists in a library you are using to do the re-inventing.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The key difference between an `ILookup` and a `Dictionary` is that the dictionary is mutable.  If you need to change the result after creation you'll need to use a Dictionary (in this case the OP may want the immutable version though).  It's also possible that there is an existing method/property typed as a `Dictionary`, and this needs to be passed into it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Well for one thing, the OP asked for a dictionary. `Dictionary` supports more operations than lookup (e.g. it can be modified), and it's possible the OP has some existing code which requires a dictionary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I would prefer the lookup case _generally_, perhaps even go from Lookup to Dictionary. @CuongLe, thanks for the edit; that's much better and I totally forgot about `Key`!

Comment: Ok, I understand now, however @Lee I am doing some remodeling and I need to hammer a nail, should I use a [Old Shoe or Glass Bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

Or you could probably simply use

```
orders.ToLookup(o => o.CustomerName).ToDictionary(g => g.Key)
```

But as Spender's answer indicates, maybe you don't need the last method, `ToDictionary`.

Comment: FYI, this will create a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<String, IGrouping<String,Order>>`. Not sure if this is an issue for kateroh or not. +1 though for something concise.

Comment: That's correct. If you don't want that extra "structure" on the dictionary values, I guess you can say `orders.ToLookup(o => o.CustomerName).ToDictionary<string, Order>(g => g.Key)`, if I'm turning the *covariance* of `IEnumerable<>` the right way inside my head.